# Can't start MongoDB v4.0

Tags: mongodb

I just installed MongoDB v4.0.2 and after I try to start the service:

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
```

and then get its status:

```
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

I get this:

`mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-09-21 15:00:05 UTC; 1s ago
  Process: 3460 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)
 Main PID: 3460 (code=exited, status=100)`

What's happening?

EDIT: `I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock (Unknown error). Another mongod instance is already running on the /var/lib/mongodb directory, terminating`

Comment: Show your logs. Status 100 is uncaught exception.

Comment: I added it to my original question

Comment: So ensure no other mongod is running e.g. `ps aux | grep mongod` and if so, delete the lock file. Otherwise stop the running instance of mongod issuing `kill -15` signal to the process.

Comment: I deleted the lock file but nothing changed! I thought it could be a permission issue, but everything seems ok...

Comment: You were right! I think another mongo instance was running! Mongo is active now! Thanks!